# Can't edit any component in GUI

Tags: java, swing

I came up with a recently problem that, any component that I add to a `JPanel` (`JTextField`, `JTextArea`, `JTable`) can't edit even when I force it, in code, to be enabled and editable. I'm using NetBeans for developing the project.

Anyone here faced this problem? Looks like I'll be forced to change all to `JFrame`. Even though, hope that someone reply this topic with some constructive idea/help.

Comment: When did the components become uneditable? When running the application or when you design the layout with Netbeans GUI editor? In the first case, provide more details about your code. On the latter case, specify the version of Netbeans, Java, and OS.

Comment: 'Looks like I'll be forced to change all to JFrame' - instead of what?

Comment: `Looks like I'll be forced to change all to a JFrame` - Sounds like you are using a JWindow. If so the see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066829/how-to-capture-keyboard-inputs-in-my-jwindow-using-java/8067372#8067372 for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `setFocusable(true)` for the top level container.

Comment: not working. Put that line in top level one and did not work, put in the next panels and still not working. damn...

Answer (score 1):

I have two reasons/opinions/thoughts as to why you are getting "errors".

1. You aren't adding the components to the panel correctly.

   ```
   panel.add(someComponent);
   panel.add(anotherComponent);
   panel.add(yetAnotherComponent);
   frame.add(panel);
   ```
2. You are overriding the default behavior for the components. All components in a JFrame, JWindow, etc. are by default enabled and editable (meaning there is an implied `setEnabled(true)` and `setEditable(true)`, respectively).